# Scala Play 2.3 WS.url(...) Configuration Error

Tags: web-services, scala, playframework-2.0

I am attempting to make a simple, unauthenticated WS call to another server on
our internal network, but I am unable to make any WS calls at all without
getting a NoSuchMethodException regarding

AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder.setConnectionTimeoutInMs(I)AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder;

### Full Stack Trace:

```
[error] Uncaught exception when running app.controllers.WSSuite:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder.setConnectionTimeoutInMs(I)Lcom/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder;
sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder.setConnectionTimeoutInMs(I)Lcom/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder;
  at play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder.configureWS(NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder.scala:45)
  at play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder.build(NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder.scala:28)
  at app.controllers.WSSuite.<init>(NotificationActionsSuite.scala:110)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) 
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:641)
  at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:294)
  at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:284)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### build.sbt

```
...

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100-jdbc4",
  "org.flywaydb" % "flyway-sbt" % "3.0",
  "org.dbunit" % "dbunit" % "2.5.0" % "test",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test",
  "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.2.0" % "test",
  "org.jdom" % "jdom" % "1.1.2"  notTransitive(),
  "org.pac4j" % "play-pac4j_scala2.11"  % "1.4.0",
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-http" % "1.7.0",
  "jp.t2v" %% "play2-auth"      % "0.13.2",
  "jp.t2v" %% "play2-auth-test" % "0.13.2" % "test",
  "javax.jms" % "javax.jms-api" % "2.0.1",
  "org.apache.activemq" % "activemq-all" % "5.11.1",
  "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "2.1.7" % "test",
  "io.gatling"            % "gatling-test-framework"    % "2.1.7" % "test",
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  ws
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)

...
```

### project/plugins.sbt

```
...
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.10") // It works from Play 2.3.2
...
```

### test/app/controllers/WSSuite.scala

```
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global 
import org.scalatestplus.play.{OneAppPerSuite, PlaySpec}
import play.api.Play.current
class WSSuite extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite 
{
  "WS library" should {
    "Hit an external web service" in {
      WS.url("http://www.google.com").get().map { response =>
        println("Body: " + response.body)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know how to trouble shoot this, as the Play Docs indicate that this
should just work.

Relevant Docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Play 2.3 and Gatling 2.1 in the same project, because of conflicting versions of AsyncHttpClient.

Play 2.3 requires AHC 1.8 while Gatling 2.1 requires AHC 1.9.

Either upgrade to Play 2.4, where AHC dependency was upgraded, or move your Gatling tests to a separate project or module where classpaths won't conflict.